# Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: meth when running

Tags: petapoco

I am having a project in which I have my API classes and in that project I have generated the Database.cs.  In my MVC project I have refenrenced the API. Uppon running the application I am having the error message as follows, can anyone help please as I can`t understand why I am having this error message.

From http://www.garethelms.org/2011/05/help-getting-started-with-petapoco/#comment-69, I can see that all the GetSetMethod() are  GetSetMethod(true) ever since the petaPOCo is installed.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: meth  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: meth
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1990:                                        } Line 1991: Line
>   1992:                                     il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
>   pc.PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true));      // poco Line
>   1993:                                     Handled = true; Line 1994:                                  }
>
> Source File: C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\API\Models\PetaPoco.cs    Line:
>   1992
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: meth]
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode,
>   MethodInfo meth) +9492330    PetaPoco.PocoData.GetFactory(String sql,
>   String connString, Boolean ForceDateTimesToUtc, Int32 firstColumn,
>   Int32 countColumns, IDataReader r) in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\API\Models\PetaPoco.cs:1992
>   PetaPoco.d__7`1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\API\Models\PetaPoco.cs:765
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>   PetaPoco.Database.Fetch(String sql, Object[] args) in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\API\Models\PetaPoco.cs:601
>   PecaTest.NewProject.API.Customer.LoadSortedByName() in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\API\Customer.cs:68
>   PecaTest.NewProject.MvcUI.Models.CustomerListModel..ctor() in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\MvcUI\Models\CustomerListModel.cs:14
>   PecaTest.NewProject.MvcUI.Controllers.CustomerController.GetIndexView()
>   in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\MvcUI\Controllers\CustomerController.cs:82
>   PecaTest.NewProject.MvcUI.Controllers.CustomerController.Index() in
>   C:\Dev\MyProjectTest\Code\MvcUI\Controllers\CustomerController.cs:19
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +409
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_a()
>   +127    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_c()
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +305
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +830
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +111    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_4() +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +140    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +52    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8969117    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

---

Customer class

```
` private int id = 0;
    public  int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = ID; }
    }

    protected string name;
    public Customer() { }

    public Customer(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
```

`

Comment: Could you please provide more information. Poco used? Usage? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was indeed with the POCO as I missed to set and get the ID

Answer (score 14):

To make the accepted answer a bit more precise. I ran into this issue when I had a property in my POCO that matched the name of a column in the database table but I didn't have a setter for the property. In my case it was a property that I was computing myself so I didn't really need the data from the table and I intended it to be read-only. Adding an empty setter fixed the problem for me.

A likely better option would be to add the Ignore attribute to that property.

I ultimately ended up removing the column from the table.

Comment: The same will happen with a privately set property too, for example: `{get; private set;}`

Answer (score 4):

Does your poco have a parameterless constructor ie; no arguments? It will need one. If you've created your own constructor with parameters you won't have a default parameterless constructor which could be causing the reflection code to fail. Maybe that's it.

Comment: Failing that, have you run the debugger and check the value of pc. Is it definitely the poco you expect it to be? I agree with Schotime we don't have enough info to go on

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem in dapper which in my poco object i defined one field as priave geter after remove private problem solved

> 

```
    public bool isObsolete { **private** get; set; }
```

change to

> 

```
    public bool isObsolete { get; set; }
```